# Reverse error in Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and slowly learning how it works. I just upgraded to 1.10 and part of my app stopped working. I know it is related to the changes made into Reverse. I have been reading and I cannot find exactly what I'm doing wrong. Almost everything works as it should with a couple of exceptions. The behavior is as follows:

1) On my app I load reservations/create, it works perfectly I can create my reservation

2) When I click create, the reservation is actually created and saved into the database, but the browser is sent to the wrong address. It gets sent to reservations/create instead of reservations/reservation number (for example reservations/2 where it shows its details) and shows a Reverse error (included in this post)

3) If I test reservations/2 for example, it shows that it was actually created.

4) Also if a go straight to reservations/ it should show a list of all the ones already create, but instead shows a Reverse error too.

I would really appreciate any help in understanding what I'm doing wrong.

**Models.py**

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    res_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Created")
    reservation_type = models.CharField(max_length=11,choices=shced_type_choices, default="rental")
    aircraft = models.ForeignKey('aircraft.Aircraft')
    renter = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("reservations:detail", kwargs={"res_number": self.res_number})
```

**Main urls.py**

```
url(r'^reservations/', include('dispatch.urls', namespace='reservations')),
```

**Dispatch.urls**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import (
    reservations_list,
    reservations_detail,
    reservations_edit,
    reservations_dispatch,
    reservations_close,
    reservations_cancel,
    reservations_create,
    reservations_close,
)


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', reservations_list),
    url(r'^(?P<res_number>\d+)/$', reservations_detail),
    url(r'^(?P<res_number>\d+)/edit/$', reservations_edit),
    url(r'^(?P<res_number>\d+)/dispatch/$', reservations_dispatch),
    url(r'^(?P<res_number>\d+)/close/$', reservations_close),
    url(r'^(?P<res_number>\d+)/cancel/$', reservations_cancel), 
    url(r'^create/$', reservations_create),
    url(r'^close/$', reservations_close),

]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import ReservationForm, CloseReservationForm
from .models import Reservation

def reservations_list(request):
    queryset = Reservation.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "List of Reservations:"

    }
    return render(request, "dispatch/list.html", context)

def reservations_detail(request, res_number=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Reservation, res_number=res_number)
    context = {
        "title": instance.renter,
        "instance": instance,

    }
    return render(request, "dispatch/details.html", context)


def reservations_create(request):
    form = ReservationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        print(instance.aircraft.hobbs)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Reservation Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
    "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "dispatch/create.html", context)
```

**Details.html**

```
{% extends "dispatch/base.html" %}
{% block head_title %}{{ block.super }} | {{instance.res_number}}{% endblock head_title %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Reservation for {{title}} on {{instance.date}}</h1>


Reservation Number: {{instance.res_number}}</br>
Date: {{instance.date}}</br>
Status: {{instance.status}}</br>
Reservation Type: {{instance.reservation_type}}</br>
Aircraft: {{instance.aircraft}}</br>
Renter's Name: {{instance.renter}}</br>
Instructor's Name: {{instance.instructor}}</br>
Expected Flight Hours: {{instance.expected_hours}} Hrs</br>
Actual Flown Hours: {{instance.flown_hours}} Hrs</br>
Reservation Created on: {{instance.created}}</br>
Last Updated on: {{instance.updated}}</br>

{% endblock content %}
```

**Create.html**

```
{% extends "dispatch/base.html" %}

{% block head_title %}{{ block.super }} | Create{% endblock head_title %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Create Reservation</h1>

<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}

{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" name="Create Reservation">

</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

[Reverse error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC6R3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your routes don't have names. So when you are using `reverse('some_name')`, you have to have such name defined. The name is `detail` in your case, so you want to do something like this (see the parameter `name`)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<res_number>\d+)/$', reservations_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Also please don't insert traceback as a screenshot. You see the link 'switch to copy-and-paste view'? Yeah, use that the next time.

Comment: yedpodtrzitko, thank you so much! that did the trick. Also thank you for letting me know about posting the traceback.

Comment: @aitor11 no need to thanks, that's what the 'accept answer' tick button is for.